# How Golang caches DNS on Win10?

Tags: go, dns

I'm trying to write a http(s) proxy for golang executable, this is what I did:

1. Write a .dll which hooks 'getaddrinfo','GetAddrInfoW','gethostbyname', redirect all domain to `localhost`.
2. Inject the .dll into golang_target.exe (now all requests are redirected to localhost)

**Expected**:
I expected all requests are redirected to localhost:80(443) and these requests will fail.

**Result**: When the .dll is injected, it doesn't take effect at once, requests still works fine. I've add MessageBox in those 'getaddrinfo ...' functions, they are not called.

But after about three minutes the .dll seems to work, all requests fail, and MessageBox popup.

**Question**: I guess golang or the Windows OS caches the dns, and refreshes the cache every couple of minutes? Is it possible for manually refreshing the cache? So I can make the .dll take effect instantly.

Comment: Go doesn't cache dns results, but depending on how you build your app, the OS might. You also might have to take into account active http connections which are being reused.

Comment: Indeed, as Jim says, Go does no DNS caching of its own; Windows most certainly does though.

Answer (score 0):

No Go (and most languages standard library) doesn't cache DNS responses and just rely on the OS. IIRC Windows and macOS will cache DNS by default but Linux distros usually don't.

If you could hook into `GetAddrInfoW` call, you would bypass Windows' cache (you could check that Go is calling the syscall in `lookupIP` method in `src/net/lookup_windows.go`) but I don't think you could hook into using DLLs because Go has its own implementation of syscall.

Other than that you could flush Windows DNS cache by running `ipconfig /flushdns`
 command.

Comment: I tried 'ipconfig /flushdns' after the exe launch, request still works, still takes some minutes that the request get fail, seems no difference.

Comment: @aj3423 Are you sure that you hooked into Go DNS lookup? (regardless of DNS caching) You could try some random domain name that you are sure that is not cached.